# Passing a dictionary list using WaitCallback()

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to pass a dictionary list to a new thread using WaitCallback and I am unable to get this working. Is this p

```
Dictionary<string, string> iRequestObjects = new Dictionary<string, string>();
iRequestObjects.Add("Query String", queryString );
iRequestObjects.Add("Item2", "ItemData");

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(iLogEventSave),iRequestObjects);

public void iLogEventSave(object state, IDictionary<object, object> dObject)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WaitCallback` is defined as `public delegate void WaitCallback(Object state)`. So what you will need to do is cast the `state` object that is passed in to the type you passed in as `state` to `QueueUserWorkItem`.

```
Dictionary<string, string> iRequestObjects = new Dictionary<string, string>();
iRequestObjects.Add("Query String", queryString );
iRequestObjects.Add("Item2", "ItemData");

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(iLogEventSave),iRequestObjects);

public void iLogEventSave(object state)
{
    IDictionary<object, object> dObject = (IDictionary<object, object>)state;
}
```

---

Note, you will get a `InvalidCastException` if you do this as `Dictionary<string, string>` can not be cast to `IDictionary<object, object>`.

You have a few options:

1. Change `iRequestObjects` to be `Dictionary<object, object>`
2. Change `dObject` to be `IDictionary<string, string>`
3. Change `dObject` to be [`IDictonary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `IDictionary<object, object>`

Comment: It's worth noting that the cast will fail at runtime.  You can't cast a `Dictionary<string, string>` to an `IDictionary<object, object>`.  `IDictionary` is not covariant in either of it's generic arguments.  Of course, the spirit of the answer still has merit.

Comment: @Servy I just realized that after I made the comment on your answer and was typing up a update while where making your comment.

Answer (score 2):

While you could modify your code a bit to pass in the state appropriately, as is described in other answers, I find that it's generally much easier to use closures to pass in data to a delegate that will be used to start a new thread, at least unless there's some compelling reason not to do so:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => iLogEventSave(iRequestObjects));
```

Then your method can have the signature you want it to have:

```
public void iLogEventSave(IDictionary<string, string> state)
```

Comment: Even though I have the accepted answer, I think this is the better solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

you cant do that. you need to cast the state/object into the expected type.

example:

```
    static void MyCallBack(object stateInfo) 
    {
        IDctionary<object, object> dict = (IDictionary<object, object>)stateInfo;    
    }
```

take a look here for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza(v=vs.110).aspx